# how can I pass a json string to object?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, object, struct

my problem is the next, I have a this json

```
{
  "nombre" : "userProfile.user.name!",
  "apaterno" : 20,
  "amaterno" : true,
  "email" : 100,
  "start_screen" : {
    "info" : true,
    "title" : false,
    "image" : 20,
    "success_btn" : "hola",
    "close_btn" : true
  }
}
```

i want to pass this json to my struct, my struct is :

```
struct person: Decodable
{
    var email : Int
    var nombre : String
    var apaterno : Int
    var amaterno: Bool

    struct start_screen {
        var title: Bool
        var info: Bool
        var image: Int
        var success_btn: String
        var close_btn: Bool
    }
}
```

with the next lines I achieved put the json in my struct, but start_screen struct can't get the data.

```
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let myStruct = try! decoder.decode(person.self, from: jsonData)
```

when I access myStruct.email I get 100, its ok, but I can't load the start_screen data, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to add a variable to `person` for `start_screen`.

```
var start_screen: start_screen
```

Then you would need to make `start_screen` `Decodable`

```
struct start_screen: Decodable
```

That should be the minimum amount of changes to get it working.

---

Additionally, you might want to make your types capitalized. `start_screen: start_screen` is really confusing looking. You can also make your variable and type names `camelCase` and have the `JSONDecoder` convert to/from `snake_case` for you. It's also the naming convention in swift. It'd look like this

```swift
struct Person: Decodable {
    var email: Int
    var nombre: String
    var apaterno: Int
    var amaterno: Bool
    var startScreen: StartScreen

    struct StartScreen: Decodable {
        var title: Bool
        var info: Bool
        var image: Int
        var successBtn: String
        var closeBtn: Bool
    }
}

let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let person = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, from: jsonData)
print(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your **Person** struct :

```
struct Person: Decodable {
var email : Int?
var nombre : String?
var apaterno : Int?
var amaterno: Bool
var start_screen: Start_screen?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case email = "email"
    case nombre = "nombre"
    case apaterno = "apaterno"
    case amaterno = "amaterno"
    case start_screen = "amaterno"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    email = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .email)
    nombre = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .nombre)
    apaterno = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .apaterno)
    amaterno = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .apaterno) ?? false
    start_screen = try values.decodeIfPresent(Start_screen.self, forKey: .start_screen)
}
```

}

This should be your **Start_screen** struct :

```
struct Start_screen: Decodable {
var title: Bool
var info: Bool
var image: Int?
var success_btn: String?
var close_btn: Bool

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case title = "title"
    case info = "info"
    case image = "image"
    case success_btn = "success_btn"
    case close_btn = "close_btn"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    title = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .title) ?? false
    info = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .info) ?? false
    image = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .image)
    success_btn = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .success_btn)
    close_btn = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .close_btn) ?? false
}
```

}

Accessing **start_screen** from **Person**  :

```
if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
   let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: jsonData)
   if let title = user.start_screen.title {
      print(title)
   }
}
```